# Can you explain the meaning of this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Can you explain to me what this JavaScript code means?

```
const TRUE = x => y => x;
const FALSE = x => y => y;
const IFELSE = p => a => b => p(a)(b);

console.log(IFELSE(TRUE)('1')('2'));  // The result is: 1
console.log(IFELSE(FALSE)('1')('2')); // The result is: 2
```

Comment: Lambda calculus.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about arrow functions in general but about the usage here (lambda functions, lambda calculus). I'd say this post is not a dupe.

Comment: I dont' think this is a duplicate, but this question doesn't have any  value except for fun: anyone with enough knowledge of Javascript can figure out what it does, and nobody writes such code in practice.

Comment: I dont think this is a dup? hes asking about currying